# Запрос SQL c AVG от суммы двух COUNT

Tags: sql, база-данных, mysql

Пытаюсь сделать подсчет записей из двух таблиц и взять среднее от суммы:

```
SELECT
                a.idDetailToUsers,
                a.DetailToUsersName,
                a.DetailToUsersPhoto,
                AVG(COUNT(b.QuestionIdUser) + COUNT(c.idAnswerToQuestion)) AS RateAnsQuest
                FROM detailtousers a INNER JOIN question b ON b.QuestionIdUser = a.idDetailToUsers
                INNER JOIN answertoquestion c ON c.AnswerToQuestionIdQuestion = a.idDetailToUsers ORDER BY RateAnsQuest DESC
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
#1111 - Invalid use of group function
```

Почему не хочет группировать по a.idDetailToUsers?

Comment: Можно сделать так:

SELECT
    a.idDetailToUsers,
    a.DetailToUsersName,
    a.DetailToUsersPhoto,
    (COUNT(b.QuestionIdUser) + COUNT(c.idAnswerToQuestion))/2  AS RateAnsQuest
    FROM detailtousers a INNER JOIN question b ON b.QuestionIdUser = a.idDetailToUsers
    INNER JOIN answertoquestion c ON c.AnswerToQuestionIdQuestion = a.idDetailToUsers GROUP BY a.idDetailToUsers

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что при использовании агрегирующих функций в SELECT можно выбирать только те столбцы, по которым есть группировка! В вашем случае запрос будет работать, если убрать вывод столбцов `a.DetailToUsersName, a.DetailToUsersPhoto`. Следующий запрос должен работать:

```
SELECT a.idDetailToUsers,
       AVG(COUNT(b.QuestionIdUser) + COUNT(c.idAnswerToQuestion)) AS RateAnsQuest
 FROM detailtousers a 
 INNER JOIN question b ON b.QuestionIdUser = a.idDetailToUsers
 INNER JOIN answertoquestion c ON c.AnswerToQuestionIdQuestion = a.idDetailToUsers
 GROUP BY a.idDetailToUsers
 ORDER BY RateAnsQuest DESC
```

**UPD#1:** С внешним запросом:

```
SELECT  t2.idDetailToUsers,
        t2.DetailToUsersName,
        t2.DetailToUsersPhoto,
        t1.RateAnsQuest
  FROM 
  (SELECT a.idDetailToUsers,
          AVG(COUNT(b.QuestionIdUser) + COUNT(c.idAnswerToQuestion)) AS RateAnsQuest
     FROM detailtousers a 
     INNER JOIN question b ON b.QuestionIdUser = a.idDetailToUsers
     INNER JOIN answertoquestion c ON c.AnswerToQuestionIdQuestion = a.idDetailToUsers
     GROUP BY a.idDetailToUsers) t1
  INNER JOIN detailtousers t2
  ON t1.idDetailToUsers = t2.idDetailToUsers
  ORDER BY RateAnsQuest DESC
```

Comment: А если сделать группировку по тем лишний столбцам, которые убрали? т-е перечислить их в GROUP BY?

Comment: Я бы посоветовал просто во внешнем запросе выбрать остальные данные!